# unable to upload .csv file and update fields in object with vf and controller

Tags: visualforce

unable  to upload .csv file and update fields in object with vf and controller.
When I am trying to upload a .csv file I receive an error:
"

```
System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 1 Error is in expression '{!ReadFile}' in component <apex:commandButton> in page fileuploader
```

can anyone say correct solution for it

Comment: It looks like an error in the code. Can you share this? What have you done so far? Have you tried the debug-logs?

Comment: yes, we are definitely going to need to see some code/VF to help with this!